# Web Api response error for get request - System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException - 500 internal server error

Tags: c#, rest

When I debug it using Postman, it could invoke the Web Api method. The controller is scaffolded using option "Web Api 2 Controller with actions, using Entity Framework" in .NET Framework 4.6.1, Web Application Web, Api project.

```
// GET: api/MovieHallDetails
public IQueryable<MovieHallDetails> GetMovieHallDetails() { 
        return db.MovieHallDetails;
}
```

These are the sample data in the table when I select it with SQL select query:

```
Id  MovieHallId Seats   SeatStatus
297 9           1,1     0
298 9           1,2     0
299 9           1,3     0
300 9           1,4     0
```

I also have many other similar Web Api methods for other tables and I could issues get request and able to get the successful web api response except for this one.

These is what return back when I test it at Postman

500 internal server error

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MovieHallDetails` does not have parameterless constructor. After added parameterles constructor, problem solved.